# Select ListView Row ASP.NET MVC WEBFORMS Scroll Position

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, webforms, selected

I am trying to do something like this;

```
Protected Sub LvTest_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvTest.ItemDataBound
    Dim C As Integer = 0
    If C = 4 Then 
        e.Item.DataItem.Selected = True 'This crashes with E.Item.DataItem.Selected is not a member ....
    End If
    C+=1

End Sub
```

I want to select the row because it is a big list and the scrollbar goes to the top and I figure if I select the ListView row then it would keep the scroll bar position after I  rebind.

Please Help..

--UPDATE
If I cannot do this is there a way I can remember the scroll position of listview.

Comment: `ItemDataBound` is a member of the Web Forms `ListView` control so this question should be tagged as Web Forms, or ASP.NET at the very least.  Please use ALL relevant tags.  Technology is as relevant as language because the WinForms and WPF `ListView` controls are quite different.

Comment: Sorry about that but I am only allowed 3 tags anyway because of my score, I will change the heading in accordance..

Comment: I'd suggest that 'webforms' is far more informative and useful than 'selected'. Those with expertise in Web Forms may well have watched that tag but who's going to watch 'selected'?

Comment: I am really sorry that I cannot set up these questions correctly. I was looking for someone to help but hey ho.

Comment: I'm just providing advice to help you ask better questions in future. I opened this question assuming that it would be WinForms.  I don't use Web Forms so I can't help with the question. If you use more appropriate tags in future, you'll help yourself and us.